# Concatinating two Flows in Akka stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to concat two Flows and I am not able to explain the output of my implementation.

```
val source = Source(1 to 10)
val sink = Sink.foreach(println)

val flow1 = Flow[Int].map(s => s + 1)
val flow2 = Flow[Int].map(s => s * 10)

val flowGraph = Flow.fromGraph(
    GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val concat = builder.add(Concat[Int](2))
      val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

      broadcast ~> flow1 ~> concat.in(0)
      broadcast ~> flow2 ~> concat.in(1)

      FlowShape(broadcast.in, concat.out)
    }
  )

source.via(flowGraph).runWith(sink)
```

I expect the following output from this code.

```
2
3
4
.
.
.
11
10
20
.
.
.
100
```

Instead, I see only "2" being printed. Can you please explain what is wrong in my implmentation and how should I change the program to get the desired output.

Comment: `source.via(flow1).concat(source.via(flow2))`. Note that you _are_ re-running `source` twice though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Akka Stream's API docs:

[`Concat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/Concat.html):

> Emits when the current stream has an element available; if the current input completes, it tries the next one

[`Broadcast`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/Broadcast.html):

> Emits when all of the outputs stops backpressuring and there is an input element available

The two operators won't work in conjunction as there is a conflict in how they work -- `Concat` tries to pull all elements from one of `Broadcast`'s outputs before switching to the other one, whereas `Broadcast` won't emit unless there is demand for ALL of its outputs.

For what you need, you could concatenate using [`concat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/concat.html) as suggested by commenters:

```
source.via(flow1).concat(source.via(flow2)).runWith(sink)
```

or equivalently, use [`Source.combine`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/operators/Source/combine.html) like below:

```
Source.combine(source.via(flow1), source.via(flow2))(Concat[Int](_)).runWith(sink)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `GraphDSL`, which is a simplified version of the implementation of [Source.combine](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/70120060b8b6de66d2944f88e8fe316c9ca4191c/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.scala#L764):

```
val sg = Source.fromGraph(
  GraphDSL.create(){ implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val concat = builder.add(Concat[Int](2))

    source ~> flow1 ~> concat
    source ~> flow2 ~> concat

    SourceShape(concat.out)
  }
)

sg.runWith(sink)
```